# How do you load a file as a List type in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a question with Python 2.5 . First, I save a file in list format as below:

```
list_f = open("list.txt", "w")
list = [{"a" : "b", "c" : 100}, {"a" : "c", "c" : 101}]
print >> list_f, list
```

So, we get a list.txt like this:

```
[{'a' : 'b', 'c': 100}, {'a' : 'c', 'c' : 101}]
```

This is its only line in this file. Notice that there are two dict objects in the list and each dict has a value in String and a value in integer .

My question is how to load the file and re-create a list object as the former one.

Comment: you should avoid to use `list` (and other python keywords or builtin) as variable names

Comment: thanks , I will be cautious .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ast
with open('list.txt') as f:
    output = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

returns `output` as a real list of dictionaries and not as its string representation `f.read()` would return.

Anyway, if you are both writing and reading the file, use some serialization interface, such as `cPickle` or `json`.

Comment: I have to work on python 2.5 . how to import ast module in Python2.5 ? there is a discussion on this question , but it seems that there is no way . http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/953807?do=post_view_threaded#953807

Comment: hi, we can put [ast.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/ast.py?view=markup) in the sys_path ,it works . my test code create only a simple list , but we need to use this on some complex list file . hope it can work well too. thank you .

Answer (score 2):

You *can* restore the object using `ast.literal_eval()`, but you actually *should* use some sane serialisation format, like JSON or Python's pickle module.

Example:

```py
# JSON
import json
# saving
with open("a.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(obj, f)
# loading
with(open("a.json") as f:
    obj = json.load(f)
```

For pickle, replace every occurrence of `json` by `pickle`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) standard library module to instead do `json.dump(my_list)` and then to read it `json.load(my_file_with_my_lists)`, which converts your list to JSON and reads it back again.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile function from builtin functions.
But better way is use http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html module for storing python datastructure in file